# Property of a primitive function of $ \frac{1}{z} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ L\left(z\right) $ be a primitive of $ \frac{1}{z} $ on some region $ D\subset\mathbb{C}^{\times} $.

I want to show that $ L\left(z\omega\right)=L\left(z\right)+L\left(\omega\right)+a $ for some constant $ a\in\mathbb{C} $, and for all $z,\omega $ such that $ z\omega\in D $.

There is another assumption that we need : assume in addition that the set $ \left\{ \left(z,\omega\right)\in D\times D\thinspace|\thinspace z\omega\in D\right\}  $ is connected.

So, here's what I have tried:

Let us define on the set $$ \left\{ \left(z,\omega\right)\in D\times D\thinspace|\thinspace z\omega\in D\right\}  $$

the following function  $$ g\left(z,\omega\right)=L\left(z\omega\right)-L\left(z\right)-L\left(\omega\right) $$

notice we have $ \nabla g\left(z,\omega\right)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}g\left(z,\omega\right),\frac{\partial}{\partial\omega}g\left(z,\omega\right)\right)=\left(\frac{\omega}{z\omega}-\frac{1}{z},\frac{z}{z\omega}-\frac{1}{\omega}\right)=\left(0,0\right) $

And thus $ g $ is constant and therefore we get the existance of such complex $ a $.

My questions are :

1.Why do we need the assumption that the set $ \left\{ \left(z,\omega\right)\in D\times D\thinspace|\thinspace z\omega\in D\right\}  $ is connected?
Is there a counterexample for a $ D $ which does not satisfy this property?

2.Is there something wrong with fixing $\omega \in D $ and then define as a function of just one variable for the fixed $\omega$, $ g\left(z\right)=L\left(z\omega\right)-L\left(z\right)-L\left(\omega\right) $, and in the same manner to deduce that $ g $ is constant? will this mean that the complex $ a $ we get would depend on $\omega$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take as $D$ the plane minus the negative half axis and as the primitive in cause the usual principal value of the logarithm for which $\Im L \in (-\pi,\pi)$; then $L(1)=0, L(e^{3\pi i/4})=3\pi i/4, L(-i)=L(e^{3\pi i/2})=-\pi/2, L(1)=L(1)+L(1)-0, L(-i)=L((e^{3\pi i/4})^2)=2L(e^{3\pi i/4})-2\pi i$ so the result doesn't hold here

Comment: @Conrad you mean the plane minus both the negative part of the real axis and the negative part of the imaginary axis?

Comment: no - the plane minus $(x,0), x \le 0$